# Is there any setTimeout equivalent in php?

Tags: php

Is there any equivalent to `javascript` `setTimeout` method in `php` ?

what I know that php is not multithreading but I could be wrong.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't. Mainly because PHP is server-sided so it wouldn't make much sense to have timed events. There is, though, the [`sleep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) function which halts the execution for a given time.

Answer (score 1):

You can do multi-threading in PHP with `pthreads`

From PHP manual:

```
pthreads  is an Object Orientated API that allows user-land multi-threading in PHP.
It includes all the tools you need to create multi-threaded applications targeted at the Web or the Console.
PHP applications can create, read, write, execute and synchronize with Threads, Workers and Stackables.
```

**References**

1) http://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/1jo517/multithreading_in_php_with_pthreads/

2) https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads

Answer (score 0):

PHP has threads so you can `fork` like you would in other multithreaded languages.

You can always make your own event-loop of course ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way that you can get a JS equivalent.  Has nothing to do with that. Are different technologies.

I dont know what are trying to do.  But you can set the max_execution_time on for php.ini file or override that value at script level.

take a look at

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php